# ¿Cuál es la relación entre el cementerio y el cemento?

Tags: etimología

Tengo entendido que la palabra **lápida** viene de "piedra" (esto debido a las historias en que se *lapida* a las adúlteras, o sea, se las mata a piedrazos).

Entonces me surgió esta duda: ¿cuál es la relación entre el **cementerio** y el **cemento**? (lingüísticamente hablando, por supuesto).

Yo me imaginaba que se relaciona con el material del que están hechas las lápidas, pero ahora entiendo, como dije arriba, que las lápidas no son de cemento sino de piedra...

¿Estoy muy perdido?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is easily answered by general reference material. See [here](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/74/12).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El [diccionario etimológico](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?cementerio) te resuelve esta duda: hay quien afirma que la palabra `cementerio` viene de `cemento`, pues es ahí donde "cementan" a los muertos, pero la afirmación no es correcta.

`Cemento` viene del latín *caementa*, que significa "piedra quebrada" (y esta a su vez de *caedere*, que significa "cortar, separar" y del sufijo *mento*).

`Cementerio` viene del griego *koimitirion* y significa "dormitorio".